# What is the below express router doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The tutorial that I am following has the following 2 router methods for getting the articles from db.

```
router.param('article', function(req, res, next, slug) {
  Article.findOne({ slug: slug})
    .populate('author')
    .then(function (article) {
      if (!article) { return res.sendStatus(404); }

      req.article = article;

      return next();
    }).catch(next);
});

router.get('/:article', auth.optional, function(req, res, next) {
  Promise.all([
    req.payload ? User.findById(req.payload.id) : null,
    req.article.populate('author').execPopulate()
  ]).then(function(results){
    var user = results[0];

    return res.json({article: req.article.toJSONFor(user)});
  }).catch(next);
});
```

I have two questions regarding the methods above,

1. How does `Promise.all()` work ?
2. Why do we need to repopulate author field in `router.get()` method when already did that in the `router.param()` method?

Comment: `Promise.all()` takes a list of promises and returns a new promise that returns a value when all the provided promises are returned. The value returned will be an array of the results from the parameter promises.

In other words it is a way to do multiple asynchronous tasks in parallel and then wait until they are all completed before continuing.

Comment: Why do we need to repopulate author field in router.get() method when already did that in the router.param() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Promise.all(iterables)
   is used when you have multiple promises that you need to be done before executing other task. In the given case

   `[ req.payload ? User.findById(req.payload.id) : null,`
   `req.article.populate('author').execPopulate() ]`
2. Populate will not be executed until a callback is passed or execPopulate is called . So your router param will not actually populate('author').
   the .then just attaches it to the req.article. When you call populate again with same path('author') then it resets any query options that was set by the previous populate call.

this is mentioned in the Mongoose docs also [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) at the end as a note